# How to redirecting input into my C program from a file and command line arguments to graph node?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, user-input, graph-algorithm

graph node as follows

```
typedef struct node{
int x_position, y_position;
int max_rate, min_rate;
char *name;
struct node * prev;
}Node;
```

input text file as follows

```
2 2 200 300 name
1 5 240 499 name2
3 5 400 500 name3
...
```

this program run with command line arguments as follows

```
./program arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5 < input.txt
```

I want to keep them all in separate variables command line arguments `assingned_val1 = arg1 ,assigned_val2 = arg2 ...,`

and a contents of a `input.txt` assign a my `Node` graph variables as follows

```
1 1 100 300 Gerald --> node( x_position = 1; y_position =1
                           min_rate = 100 ; max_rate = 300
                           name = "Gerald" 
2 3 200 450  Yennefer --> node( x_position = 2; y_position =3
                           min_rate = 200 ; max_rate = 450
                           name = "Yennefer"
```

...
 How it can be solved using C programming ?

Comment: _"I want to keep them all in separate variables"_ well you can do this, but what types should they be? And you can parse the input with `scanf("%d %d %d %d %s\n", ...)`

Comment: all of them integer

Comment: then you can use [`strtol`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `atoi` to convert string to int, and `strcpy` to copy string to string:

```
    int arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4;
    char arg5[256];

    arg1 = atoi(argv[1]);
    arg2 = atoi(argv[2]);
    arg3 = atoi(argv[3]);
    arg4 = atoi(argv[4]);
    strcpy(arg5, argv[5]);
```

For getting info from file, you can use `fgets` and `sscanf`. This example below just for array of `count` node (not for linked list, but you can use this idea for linked list). `fgets` for reading the file then store value of file into the line. The, you can use `sscanf` to assign info from this line to each value of struct.

```
    int count = 1;
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        n = realloc(n, count * sizeof(Node));
        n[count-1].name = malloc(sizeof(char) * 16);
        if(!n)
            return - 1;
        sscanf(line, "%d %d %d %d %s\n", &n[count-1].x_position, &n[count-1].y_position, &n[count-1].min_rate, &n[count-1].max_rate, n[count-1].name);
        count++;
    }
```

The complete code for test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node{
    int x_position, y_position;
    int max_rate, min_rate;
    char *name;
    //struct node * prev;
}Node;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    char line[256];
    int arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4;
    char arg5[256];
    Node * n = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if(!n)
        return - 1;
    FILE * file = fopen(argv[6], "r");
    if (!file)
        return -1;
    arg1 = atoi(argv[1]);
    arg2 = atoi(argv[2]);
    arg3 = atoi(argv[3]);
    arg4 = atoi(argv[4]);
    strcpy(arg5, argv[5]);

    int count = 1;
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        n = realloc(n, count * sizeof(Node));
        n[count-1].name = malloc(sizeof(char) * 16);
        if(!n)
            return - 1;
        //printf("%s", line); 
        sscanf(line, "%d %d %d %d %s\n", &n[count-1].x_position, &n[count-1].y_position, &n[count-1].min_rate, &n[count-1].max_rate, n[count-1].name);
        count++;
    }

    printf("\narg1= %d, arg2 = %d, arg3 = %d, arg4 = %d, arg5 = %s\n", arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5);

    for(int i = 0; i < count-1; i++) {
        printf(" %d  %d  %d  %d  %s\n",
        n[i].x_position, n[i].y_position, n[i].min_rate, n[i].max_rate, n[i].name);
    }

}
```

Result:

```
#cat text.txt

2 2 200 300 name
1 5 240 499 name2
3 5 400 500 name3
./test 1 2 3 4 abc text.txt

arg1= 1, arg2 = 2, arg3 = 3, arg4 = 4, arg5 = abc
 2  2  200  300  name
 1  5  240  499  name2
 3  5  400  500  name3
```

Comment: thank you so much its working but i wanna get stdin input.txt ./program arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5 < input.txt

Comment: what do you want when you type `< input.txt` ? i dont understand, you want to copy the infor from input.txt to arg(s) ?

Comment: "< input.txt" this is stdin processing on command line meaning whatever input txt file you want directing it into the program.The above program you type only reads files with "input.txt" name.if I want him to read the file with another name ,it can't be done without changing the code

Comment: if you want to read the file with another name,  change the name in command line (argv[6]).  You have to change nothing in the code.

Comment: of course but i change the code and failed  "< input.txt" and must to be in this format.(I didn't write it above. sorry about that)

Comment: so, using `fgets` with `stdin`, and `scanf` for other arguments. Then `./program < input.txt` will be ok

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an input file, such this one containing the data you show eg.

> 1 1 100 300 Gerald
>   2 3 200 450 Yennefer
>   ...

Then pass just one command line argument, the path and name of the file eg:
 `executable.exe "C:\\filename.txt"`
This will allow the program to more easily accommodate as many players as needed in one step, and eliminate user input, which is prone to syntax inconsistencies, making parsing the data difficult or impossible.

This file can be read and parsed as shown below using the following functions:
[fopen](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen.htm) ( and [fclose](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fclose.htm) )
[fgets](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm)
[strtok](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm),
[strtol](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtol.htm).

Code to do the read and parsing part (with minimum error checking) follows:

```
typedef struct node{
    int x_position;
    int y_position;
    int max_rate;
    int min_rate;
    char *name;
    struct node * prev;
}Node;

int linecount(const char *file);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char line[80];
    char *tok = NULL;
    char *temp;
    errno = 0;
    int count = 0;

    if(argv != 2) 
    { 
        //exit with message
    }

    count = linecount(argv[1]);
    Node *n = calloc(count, sizeof(*n));

    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(fp)
    {
        while(fgets(line, 80, fp))
        {
            tok = strtok(line, " ");//parse x_position
            if(tok)
            {
                n->x_position = strtol(tok, &temp, 0);
                tok = strtok(NULL, " ");//parse y_position
                if(tok)
                {
                    n->y_position = strtol(tok, &temp, 0);
                    tok = strtok(NULL, " ");//parse max_rate
                    if(tok)
                    {
                        n->max_rate = strtol(tok, &temp, 0); 
                        tok = strtok(NULL, " ");//parse min_rate
                        if(tok)
                        {
                            n->min_rate = strtol(tok, &temp, 0);
                            tok = strtok(NULL, " ");//parse name
                            if(tok)
                            {
                                strcpy(n->name, tok);
                            }
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;

}

int linecount(const char *file)
{
    char line[80];
    int i = 0;

    FILE *fp = fopen(file, "r");
    if(fp)
    {
        while(fgets(line, 80, fp))
        {
            i++;
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return i;
}
```